# HTML Textarea with Rich Font Controls

Tags: html, .net-core, textarea

I was curious how I can add this type of textarea to my CSHTML page (MVC .NetCore)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Summernote](https://summernote.org/).
I am currently using one in my project

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.18/dist/summernote-lite.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.18/dist/summernote-lite.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea asp-for="Description" id="summernote"></textarea>
    <script>
        $('#summernote').summernote({
        placeholder: 'Description goes here....',
        height:'25vh',
        toolbar: [
        ['style', ['style']],
          ['font', ['bold', 'underline', 'clear']],
          ['color', ['color']],
          ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
          ['table', ['table']],
          ['insert', ['link', 'picture']],
          ['view', ['fullscreen', 'codeview', 'help']]
        ]
        });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```